# how to capture screenshots of sharepoint 2010 dialogs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Sharepoint 2010 "modal dialog windows" emitted from IE can't be captured with PrtScn or Alt-PrtScn like "normal" windows. I have searched for how to do this and come up empty.

I am using Remote Desktop from Windows 7 to access machines at my office via Watchguard Mobile VPN for SSL. I am careful to make the Remote Desktop session occupy the full screen of the monitor; in turn, the IE browser is maximized to take that whole screen.

During interactions with Central Admin or really any site, there are times when SP2010 emits a dialog of some sort. I would like to capture an image of the dialog itself - i.e. none of the "darkened background" behind the dialog.

Is there a good way to capture these dialogs?

Comment: use Windows 7's snipping tool. It allows you to draw rectangle for capture

Answer (score 3):

Use a screenshot tool.  The Windows 7 snipping tool Steve B mentioned works OK.  However, you might give Greenshot a try.  (http://getgreenshot.org/) It is open source (free) and it works quite well.

Comment: Cropper (http://cropper.codeplex.com/) is another free screen capture tool. They are many. Use a free one. Find the one that best meets your needs.